# Maven build - Directory Structure

Tags: maven, maven-3

Please guide since i wanted to understand on the build tool maven 'directory structure' intelli j as IDE where main/test divided into two separate folders but both have the same files.

Ps- I recently moved into QA automation so want to understand it better.
FYI per maven main website:
a. The main directory is the root directory for source code related to the application itself, not test code.
b. The test directory contains the test source code.

Answer (score 0):

Maven search for the files in the below directory structure.

```
src/main/java - Source Java files 
src/main/resources - Source resource files 
src/test/java - Test cases 
src/test/resources - Test resource files
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this site would be helpful to you: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Maven uses a strict folderstructure. Are you sure, that there are the same files in the folders? As Bhargav Kumar R mentioned before, in the test-folder there will be your test-classes, in the resource-folder there will be the resources for your tests.